# How to get (print) the current time inside the watir gem file?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, watir-classic, ruby-watir

I would like to print the current time the function is called inside the watir gem file.

Eg:
inside /watir/element/select.rb

I need to print the current time, consider when the select_by is called. I tried by adding

```
require 'time'
..
..
def select_by
puts Time.now
..
```

But, it is showing error as

```
`NoMethodError in setup: undefined method `now' for Watir::Time:Class",
"C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page-object-2.1.1/lib/page-object/platforms/watir/page_object.rb:1068:in `instance_eval'"
"(eval):1:in `process_watir_call'",`
```

Comment: Try `puts ::Time.now`.

Comment: It works for me, You don't have to require time either.

Comment: Thanks @orde, it works!!